# Import Excel from SharePoint online to SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

I have SharePoint Online and SQL Server 2014.

I have document library in SPO with multiple Excel documents.

I would like to use SSIS to read data from files and import data to the DB in SQL Server.

Could SSIS use files in SPO library as Excel source?

What is the best way to import Excel files from SPO to SQL DB? I have to repeat the task daily.

Thanks,
AP

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Hi @Asher... not yet.